# How to connect with a database outside the project in windows store apps?

Tags: database, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I have a database in my windows tablet and don't want to include it in my project, is there any way to connect with my DB stored outside the project by giving the path like c:/MyDBFolder/db.sqlite. ???

Comment: I think you need your database within the application..Apps are sandboxed for security in wp8 . Try reading from SharedStorage [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815144/wp8-copy-sharedstorge-file-directly-into-isolatedstorage)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing this for a project. However I do not access the database from my application using a path.

To access my database I created a service who's entire purpose is to do SQL queries on my database and return the result.

Look into `Service Reference` in visual studio. This allows you to connect directly to your service by giving it an url (or the localhost of the service if working in local).

So let's say you have a SelectCommand method on your service you could simply call it like this :

```
        Dim service As New ServiceReference1.Service1Client(ServiceReference1.Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService1)
        Dim returnedString As String = Await service.SelectCommandAsync()
```

There is probably a way to use your database from the application but I have not found it as this is the way I first tried doing it. The way to proceed which I have explained gives you better security and separates your project very well making it very organised and easy to use.